# How can i sort the directories on hard disk in case the user deleted one of the directories?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method:

```
private void CreateAnimatedGif(bool ToCreate)
{
    string combined = null;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(sf);
    FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles("*.gif");
    if (simtest == fi.Length - 1)
    {
        simtest = 0;
    }

    if (AnimatedGifFiles.Count == 0)
        startTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (ToCreate == false)
    {
        combined = Path.Combine(sf, fi[simtest].FullName);
        AnimatedGifFiles.Add(combined);//last_file);
        simtest += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (AnimatedGifFiles.Count > 1)
        {
            dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(AnimatedGifDirectory);
            AnimatedGifDirectoryEvent = "Rain event " + (dirs.Length + 1);
            string eventDir = Path.Combine(AnimatedGifDirectory, 
                AnimatedGifDirectoryEvent);
            if (!Directory.Exists(eventDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(eventDir);
            }
            string outputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(eventDir, 
               string.Format(
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "Event-{0:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss}_{1:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss}.gif", 
                    startTime, DateTime.Now));
            unfreezWrapper1.MakeGIF(AnimatedGifFiles, outputFile, 80, true);
        }
        AnimatedGifFiles.Clear();
    }
}
```

I'm using dirs.Length to create the directories names with a number for example if there are no directories so the first one will be: "Rain event 1" then the next one will be "Rain event 2"

But if there is a situsation that i have 4 directories for example "Rain event 1"....."Rain event 4"
And the user delete the directory "Rain event 3"

So now i will have 3 directories and not sorted: "Rain event 1","Rain event 2","Rain event 4"

The next time dirs.Length will be 3 and the next directory will be "Rain event 4" but it's already exist so it will create the new file inside "Rain event 4"

What i need it to do in this case is to rename "Rain event 4" To "Rain event 3" and that the next directory will be "Rain event 4"

Or if i have Rain event 1 , Rain event 2 , Rain event 3 , Rain event 4
And i deleted event 2 and event 3 directories so now Rain event 4 should be renamed to Rain event 2 and the next directory should be Rain event 3.

The problem i think now is how to renemae the directories to be in the order for example Rain event 4 to be Rain event 2.

Since i'm doing:

```
dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(AnimatedGifDirectory);
```

Each time then the next directory will be ok. The problem is to rename the directories in case one or more have been deleted.

Comment: Another way is to use a variable *rainEventIndex* and use it to rename *AnimatedGifDirectoryEvent = "Rain event " + rainEventIndex*. Keep this variable to a *txt* file. Every time your app start, load it from the file. When your program closes write the new value to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List the directories, sort them by name, then iterate on the list of directories. If at any moment the directory index and directory name don't match, rename it. here some pseudocode

```
var listDirs = GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.Name);
for (var directoryIndex = 1; directoryIndex <= listDirs.Count; directoryIndex++)
{
    if (directoryIndex != listDirs[directoryIndex-1].Name) {
         Rename(listDirs[directoryIndex-1], directoryIndex);
    }
}
```

Please be aware that you need to create directories with a sufficiently high padding of zeroes in order for "Dir10" not to precede "Dir2"